# What could "messy candy" mean?

Tags: definition, word-meaning

A grandmother is going to a store and making a list of what to buy. She's discussing the list with her friend.

Candy. I'll buy **messy candy**. That's what my grandchildren would like. **Messy candy**. If you'd had grandchildren, Mellie, they'd have been children who never ate between meals, who were sickly.

Now, basically, dictionaries indicate that "messy" is somethning dirty or causing a mess. But the last sentense makes me think that "messy" could mean some sort of food which makes children not "sickly", but roly-poly or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have ever seen what a small child looks like after eating anything that contains chocolate... that's what messy means.

Like this...

[image]

I think that the comment about **sickly** is a criticism of Mellie's potential abilities as a grandparent, and does not relate in any way to the sweets.

Comment: A picture paints a thousand words.

Answer (score 0):

"messy candy" means, to the grandmother, a specific candy, which in all probability is, itself, messy.

There is, for example, a dessert called "Eton Mess". It is broken fragments of meringue mixed messily into a gloopy mixture of cream and pulped (and/or chopped) berries.

The candy is likely to have a disordered, untidy or confused appearance, but there's an outside chance it simply makes a mess when eaten, and an even slimmer chance it is served in a pulpy state.

But "messy candy" is just a specific type of candy, as are rock candy, boilings, tablet, toffee, hard candy, etc.